# How to delete a bunch of NSData in NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I stored some setting for the peripheral that connected to the iOS device, but I want to add a button for the user to delete this peripheral, this means I must delete all setting related to this peripheral.

The store for this is simple using NSData:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.appDelegate.defaultBTServer.selectPeripheralInfo];
[defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:self.appDelegate.defaultBTServer.selectPeripheralInfo.uuid];
[defaults synchronize];
```

But how to delete the setting related to this selectPeripheralInfo.uuid?
I found the

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:application.defaultBTServer.selectPeripheralInfo.uuid];
```

cannot work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might not be using the same key to add and remove the data. To add, you used:

```
self.appDelegate.defaultBTServer.selectPeripheralInfo.uuid
```

but to remove the data you used:

```
application.defaultBTServer.selectPeripheralInfo.uuid
```

If the values of those expressions aren't exactly the same, you won't be able to remove the data that you added because, obviously, the key will be wrong. So, check that.

Also, make sure that you call `[defaults synchronize]` after removing to update the defaults in storage.